# Perl CGI Meta tags

Tags: perl, cgi

Per http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html to make meta tags, the following example is given:

> ```
> print start_html(-head=>meta({-http_equiv => 'Content-Type',-content => 'text/html'}))
> ```

However using the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
$cgi->autoEscape(undef);
$cgi->html({-head=>meta({-http_equiv => 'Content-Type',-content => 'text/html',-charset=>'utf-8'}),-title=>'Test'},$cgi->p('test'));
```

I get the following error:

> $ perl test.cgi  Undefined subroutine
>   &main::meta called at test.cgi line 8.

I'm trying to generate the following tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Please stop using the dirty old CGI.pm. Use instead a modern and clean web engine such as [Dancer](http://www.perldancer.org/) or [Mojolicious](http://mojolicious.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `meta` sub is not imported automatically when you `use CGI;`. Try with

```
use CGI "meta";
```

(or `":all"`).

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw(:all);

my $cgi = new CGI;
$cgi->autoEscape(undef);
$cgi->charset('utf-8');
print
    $cgi->start_html(
        -head  => meta({-http_equiv => 'Content-Type', -content => 'text/html'}),
        -title => 'Test'
    );
```

But, are you 100% sure than want use CGI for web development and not something better, like PSGI/Plack?

Comment: Choices are limited, I am making a page to work inside of Netcool/Omnibus, which uses its own Websphere HTTP server it plays best with Perl.

Comment: PSGI/Plack **IS** perl. ;) but, ok, i don't know Omnibus. Anyway, if Omnibus can act as a proxy, here should be no problem, because you simply proxying requests to Plack. And Plack really speed up any perl web-app development. ($0.02) :)

Answer (score 1):

This post is quite old but the solution is easy: the meta is a method of the object $cgi so use it as method.

your example

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;
$cgi->autoEscape(undef);
$cgi->html({-head=>$cgi->meta({-http_equiv => 'Content-Type',-content=>'text/html',-charset=>'utf-8'}),-title=>'Test'},$cgi->p('test'));
```

I simply added $cgi-> in fromt of meta.